# NSUserDefaults setting

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Im setting a value in `viewDidLoad` so it can be a default settings, so whenever I load into that view controller It will have a default value already.

Im using `NSUserDefaults` here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setInteger:1 forKey:@"defaultKey"];

    NSInteger defaultKey = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"defaultKey"];

    if (defaultKey == 1){
    // do something 1
    } else if ( defaultKey == 2){
    // do something 2
    }
}
```

But what I wanted is when a button is pressed for example button2,

```
-(IBAction) button2Pressed:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setInteger:2 forKey:@"defaultKey"];
}
```

it will change its value. So for example I load that ViewController again then

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setInteger:2 forKey:@"defaultKey"];
```

will be its setting the next it is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    NSInteger defaultKey = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"defaultKey"];

    if (defaultKey == 1){
    // do something 1
    } else if ( defaultKey == 2){
    // do something 2
    }
   else 
   {
        //for the first time
          NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setInteger:1 forKey:@"defaultKey"];
   } 
}
```

and

```
-(IBAction) button2Pressed:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setInteger:2 forKey:@"defaultKey"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
NSInteger defaultKey = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"defaultKey"];
    if(defaultKey == 0){
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [prefs setInteger:1 forKey:@"defaultKey"];
    }else if (defaultKey == 1){
        // do something 1
    } else if ( defaultKey == 2){
        // do something 2
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense. You should start by setting it has a default value (1 or 2). In my honest opinion you should do this on the AppDelegate:

```
  NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  // it will return 0 if it doesn't exist
  if([prefs integerForKey:@"defaultKey"] == 0){
       [prefs setInteger:1 forKey:@"defaultKey"];
  }
```

This way you have setted the default value. After that you can keep this logic in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSInteger defaultKey = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"defaultKey"];

    if (defaultKey == 1){
    // do something 1
    } else if ( defaultKey == 2){
    // do something 2
    }
}
```

And then use the rest of your logic when the button is pressed:

```
-(IBAction) button2Pressed:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setInteger:2 forKey:@"defaultKey"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things:
1. Every time you update the user defaults to persist your changes you should do:

```
[prefs synchronize];
```

2.Use this code:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger defaultKey = [prefs integerForKey:@"defaultKey"];
if(defaultKey == 0) //This is when you haven't set it and as it's integer you will get 0
{
    [prefs setInteger:1 forKey:@"defaultKey"];
    [prefs synchronize];
    //Do whatever you will do when it's 1
}
else if(defaultKey == 1)
{
   //Do something else
}
else if(defaultKey == 2)
{
  //Do something else
}
```

Comment: You do _not_ need to call synchronise every time you update defaults. If you did, what would be the point of having it as a separate method?

Comment: Yes you don't because synchronize is called periodically but what happens if he presses the button and immediately after that receives a phone call? Will the settings be persisted on the disk?

Comment: You could say the same about pressing the home button. I think you have to assume the defaults object takes care of that itself, probably by listening for notifications.